# Portfolio not working after append data

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a custom Basic `HTML Template`. Its has a portfolio working with `JQuery`. I wanted to add `portfolio images` dynamically. So, What I did is, I've get the `DATA` from `XML` file and then append those to the `HTML` page. It's working fine. But, now `Portfolio` not working. Any Suggestions?

**Here Append Code**

```
$(data).find('imageGroup').each(function () {
    var imageGroup = $(this);
    if (imageGroup.length) {
        var m = '<ul class="portfolio-items col-4">\n';
        imageGroup.find('image').each(function () {
            m += '<li class="portfolio-item ' + $(this).attr('group') + '">\n';
            m += '<div class="item-inner">\n';
            m += '<div class="portfolio-image">\n';
            m += '<img src="' + $(this).attr('thumb') + '" alt="">\n';
            m += '<div class="overlay">\n';
            m += '<a class="preview btn btn-danger" title="' + $(this).attr('info') + '" href="' + $(this).attr('full') + '"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>\n';
            m += '</div>\n';
            m += '</div>\n';
            m += '<h5>' + $(this).attr('des') + '</h5>\n';
            m += '</div>\n';
            m += '</li><!--/.portfolio-item-->\n';
        });
        m += '</ul>\n';
    }
    $('.box').append(m);
});
```

This is the **code** by the developer of the template that setting up the portfolio items.

```
jQuery(function($) {
//alert("developer.js");
    //PrettyPhoto
    $("a.preview").prettyPhoto({
        social_tools: false
    });

    //Isotope
    $(window).load(function(){
        $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
        $portfolio.isotope({
            itemSelector : 'li',
            layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });
        $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
        $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
            $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Also, I can provide you any code that I miss here. It will help you to solved the issue. I couldn't understand what I have to do. If anyone can point me out. It would be pleasure.

Thanks StackOverflowers

**When I use alert inside developer.js portfolio working fine. If not it's not working. How to solve this.**

Comment: can you make a fiddle please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation to attach events to dynamically added element.:

```
    $('.box').on('click','.portfolio-filter >li>a', function(){
        $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
```

you will also need to attach isotope plugin after appending data.

Comment: @yeshansachithak: yes, you need to ensure that DOM is ready when you are attaching the events to them or use event delegation. event delegation does not work in many plugins so you need to attach the plugins after appending the content.

Comment: I got a issue. I change the order. and then add one alert box to that `developer script file`. When I used alert. everything is working. If I remove the alert from the file. It's not working. Why? ~_~

Comment: @yeshansachithak: that is because DOM is not completely loaded using append. placing alert gives it enough time to execute a while later. that will even work if you debug the code through console without alert.

Comment: I used `condole.log("loaded")` without using alert. But, not working as I use alert. Can you please tell me what I should do? I already used `$(document).ready()`. How can I realized `DOM` is fully loaded or not?

Comment: Use delegation the way i have mentioned it.

Comment: But, I am appending data to the div when document is ready. Not in a Click Event. How could I do it to that?

Comment: That should even work when you add the code in beginning of DOM ready.